# how to shuffle image in scenekit at any cube in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scenekit

i am working on SceneKit now.i have to show image random at any cube in using scenekit. i have created one shape in scenekit and want to shuffle images randomly at any cube.

here is my code :

```
 arrImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"imgColor1",@"imgColor2",nil];
```

code to add image in cube

```
int randomIndex = arc4random()%[arrImages count];
SCNMaterial *met1 = [[SCNMaterial alloc]init];
met1.diffuse.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrColor objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
//met1.diffuse.contents = [arrColor objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
[met1 setName:[arrImages objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];

[arr addObject:met1];
```

// Code to add image in SCNBOX

```
        SCNBox *Box = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:6.0 height:6.0 length:6.0 chamferRadius:Radius];
        boxNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:Box];
        [arr addObject:boxNode];
        [Box setMaterials:arr];
```

how to display image random at any cube ?

Comment: What is in arrColor? Should that not be arrImages?

Comment: @Xartec yes you are right.Question is edited now